# VMware DRS event log?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

Does VMware DRS log the VM migration events that it generates to anywhere?  I'm trying to get a list of all the VM migrations over the last month or so, and am coming up dry.  We're on vSphere 4.0, running on a cluster of 13 ESX blades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logs for DRS are in `drmdump\` More information on vSphere log file locations is [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021804).

Answer (score 2):

I'm scared that you're still on vSphere 4.0 ;)

But from the vSphere client GUI, selecting the cluster, going to DRS and choosing the "History" option is one method.

This can also be gleaned from "Tasks and Events" through filtering on the relevant events.